# how to set up an asp.net mvc app for AD B2C "auth code flow" authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

It states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)
that going forward, we must prefer the auth code flow method since "With the plans for third party cookies to be removed from browsers, the implicit grant flow is no longer a suitable authentication method."

I have set up an asp.net mvc 4 web application according to the sample app [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/tree/master/TaskWebApp). It works when I set up my app registration in AD B2C directory for Access Tokens (used for implicit grant flows). If I switch to "ID Tokens (for implicit and hybrid flows)" as the documentation recommends, I get error that my application is not setup for it.

As I understand from the documentation, I would have to specifiy separate endpoins for /authorize and/token to fetch a token after authorization. I am not sure from looking at the sample though how exactly I can do this. Below is the ConfigureAuth method as you can see in the sample code on github link provided:

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
            CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(WellKnownMetadata, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = ClientId,
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,

                // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },

                // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },

                // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {ReadTasksScope} {WriteTasksScope}",

                // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: There is the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa) using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) on Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Hi @Riz. The "Prefer the auth code flow" recommendation is related to a browser-based single page application, not a server-based web application like yours, so you can continue to enable ID tokens and/or access tokens for your application registration.

Comment: ah got it. Thanks @ChrisPadgett!

Comment: @Riz If you have solution, you can post your answer here to help more  forum users.